# Вызов скрипта из другого скрипта на JS

Tags: javascript

Допустим, у меня есть два файла (назовем их `foo.js` и `bar.js`). Мне нужно из `bar.js` вызвать функцию, находящуюся `foo.js`. Например, файлы содержат следующее:

foo.js:

```
function foo() {
    return true;
}
```

bar.js:

```
function loadScript(src, func) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.async = false;
    document.body.append(script);
}
```

Я уже понял, как загружать скрипты, но не понимаю, как вызвать что-либо или обратиться к чему-либо  через функцию `loadScript`, то есть, если точнее, **мне нужно вызвать функцию `func` (второй аргумент) как бы "от имени" `foo.js`.**

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function loadScript(src, func) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;
    document.body.append(script);
  });
}

loadScript('foo.js').then(() => foo());
```